# What does "$ make" and "$ make modules" do when compiling/building the kernel?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I'm trying to Build the configured kernel. So my coworker told me to type in the terminal

`make`

then afterwards

`make modules`

I tried to google but the closest result is [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) but when I scroll down, it shown `umake`, not `make`.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu -- that's where you made your mistake in your Google search.  Start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) instead.

Comment: Read `man make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to get around to answering your actual question, but I'm going to take the roundabout way to get there so that you have better context.

tldr: The package you need is `make` or `build-essential`. You need to be in the same directory as your linux source code and have a .config file configured (which it sounds like you already do). Then run those commands. Google keywords that might help are "compile linux kernel"

So `make` is a build system. It allows you to run a series of compile commands (or any commands, really), recursively through a directory structure. It uses a simple system for only compiling programs with changes.

Make allows for the declaration of "targets." Traditionally a target is a filename, and it is followed by which files it depends on.

So a simple example is:

```
helloworld: helloworld.c helloworld.h
    gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

This would be stored in a file call `Makefile` and it tells make that in order to build the helloworld file (compiled binary), you run `gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld` and if helloworld already exists, don't do anything unless there are changes to helloworld.c or helloworld.h that are newer than the helloworld file.

If this is the only rule in the makefile, running `make` will invoke this rule (as it's the first rule) and attempt to build `helloworld` but it could also be explicitly invoked by running `make helloworld`

Makefiles are usually much more complicated and might look more like this (this is a heavily contrived example and I realize that a makefile will almost never look like this, but it's good for explaining):

```
hello: hello.o libhello.o
    gcc hello.o libhello.o -o hello

hello.o: hello.c hello.h
    gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o

libhello.o: libhello.c libhello.h
    gcc -c libhello.c -o libhello.o
```

So if you run `make` or `make hello` this make file will check hello.o and libhello.o, if they don't exist, it will look for those targets, and thus find out how to build hello.o and libhello.o and THEN build the hello binary like you asked in the first place. This allows you to specify dependencies a level at a time and make figures out what order to compile everything to make it work (this also can save compile time if one of your library haven't changed, you don't need to recompile that object).

You can specify a target without any dependencies, in this case it will only run if the target file does not exist. Furthermore, your target doesn't have to be a file that is created by that rule. For example:

```
clean:
   rm hello *.o
```

This allows you to run `make clean` and it will delete the compiled binary and the object files. Since it doesn't actually create a file named `clean`, every time you run `make clean` this rule is executed and cleans up your working directory. This is called a phony target and they're used quite often. `make install` is one you're likely to see often to install a program that you've built with make.

### Back to your original question

So, the linux kernel uses make to build. It has a bunch of phony targets, when in the root of the Linux source, run `make help` to show you the targets. Normally you start with one of the targets that launches a program to help you build a `.config` file. These would be `make config`, `make menuconfig`, `make xconfig`, and several others.

`make` will run the default target which compiles the kernel using the options specified in the .config file. `make modules` will compile only the bits marked as modules in the `.config` file. Between these two commands you should end up with a vmlinuz kernel and bunch of kernel module binaries. What the Linux Kernel is/does is beyond the scope of this post, but the short story is that it is the software central to the operating system (if the whole system is a nut, then the kernel would be the central core, right?). It runs at the highest level of privilege on the processor and is the only piece of software that interacts directly with memory and hardware, and all other software on the system talks to the kernel to broker access to the hardware. (there are about 20 caveats in that description, but that covers the the most common 80% of how things work).

But hopefully that gives you enough context to search for more helpful information, if you search for "compile linux kernel" you should come up with a half dozen resources at all levels of complexity. The official guidance is at [linux.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/index.html), but it gets in the weeds very quickly and isn't very helpful if this is your first time.

In Ubuntu (and most distros), make is in the `make` package, so it is installed with `sudo apt install make` however, to build the kernel, you'll need other programs too, so you'd generally want to install the build toolchain and accessories with `sudo apt install build-essential` which includes make.

Comment: Right in the heart. Thank you very much!